Display a random image from a TypedArray in Kotlin, but resources doesn't exist
The goal I am trying to achieve is to import a random image from a TypedArray in res/values/arrays.xml
But before attempting to display a random photo, I am having issues with the "resources" in the following code. Where in Android Studio it is appearing as a problem.
Im following along the syntax as presented on developer.android.com link here
val images: TypedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images)
I've tried using previous solutions on Stack Overflow but they seem to be outdated now such as using "getResources()" link here

where exactly you are using this val images: TypedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images) line in your app?

@dev.tejasb
I am currently writing it in the beginning of a function as such:
@Composable fun foo(){     val images: TypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.arrayimages) /// }

what error Android Studio is showing?

can you try this:
val images = stringArrayResource(R.array.images)?

Android Studio is saying it is an Unresolved reference, pretty sure its imported to mainactivity.kt as import android.content.res.Resources
val images = stringArrayResource(R.array.images) does not throw any issues for me

so, is it the solution for you? if yes, I'll add it as answer so you can accept it

Use this:
val images = stringArrayResource(R.array.images)

instead of:
val images: TypedArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.images)

